# Does ApplicationRessource.properties file can be in another locale than EN

Tags: localization, struts2, internationalization

Is the Struts2 file `applicationRessource.properties` can be in another locale than English. I know I can have some other files like `ApplicationRessource_fr.properties` or `ApplicationRessource_es.properties`.

My main question concerns only the `ApplicationRessource.properties`. My default language will be French and I don't want to have a file like `ApplicationRessource_fr.properties`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Of course it **can** be. But you should also have `_fr` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution we found. We use 3 files. ApplicationRessource.properties who are in french, ApplicationRessource_fr.properties who is empty and ApplicationRessource_en.properties who contains the english translations

Answer (score 0):

You must have a file like `ApplicationRessource_fr.properties` if you want to use French locale. You can also have a default language file which will be used if no locale is requested. The essential part of the application include the interceptor to intercept the requested locale, you can also switch the locale per request.

> It's likely no i18n interceptor on the action stack or you don't have
>   resource bundles for the used locale or default locale used by the
>   JVM.
>
> ```
> Essentially, the i18n Interceptor pushes a locale into the ActionContext map upon every request. The framework components that
> support localization all utilize the ActionContext locale.
> ```

Comment: Presently, I have two files a ApplicationRessource.properties who are in french and a ApplicationRessource_en.properties. My website is in English when I first connect. Does Struts2 take by default the browser Locale?

on the first connect on the website, i get 
      (Locale) request.getSession().getAttribute(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE); equal to null. Normally, it supposed to take the default applicationRessource file (who are in french). Am I right? Why my texts are still in English and how can I force Struts to take my french file (default)

Comment: I already tried ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(localeObj); where localeObj is set as new Locale("fr_CA"); but it does not work.

Comment: Y need to use two parameters constructor.